# Can I read a csv file inside of a Mongo Shell Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Basically I have a file of strings and I need to query against mongo to see if they exist in our database.

So I need to loop through a file and query mongo with a find query using the string from the file and then look at the results and increment some counters I have.

I am trying to do this using a shell script and calling mongo using --eval option but it's running slow.  It's been over an hour and hasn't finished a 120,000 queries.   I am thinking it would be faster if I could do it in a javascript file so it doesn't have to make the connection for each query.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Karen

Answer (score 10):

Better option would be to use the native shell method [cat()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cat/).

Lets say, your file has following content and situated at */home/desktop/myfile.txt*

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

Following code will let you get the file content as array in **string** var:

```
$> var string = cat('home/desktop/myfile.txt');
$> string = string.split('\n');
$> db.records.find({field: {$in: string}});
```

Comment: this works great but I'm wondering how to loop over a file contents in the R3 GUI

Comment: This works but loads the entire file in memory because of which larger files cannot be processed. Any other way to process files in millions with javascript?

Answer (score -1):

For bulk imports like this, you're usually better off with [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). You may have to munge the CSV file to meet the requirements, but it will perform the final database operation over a single connection.

Comment: I want to just do a find query.  I don't have any inserts.