# How to process millions in a file inside Mongo shell with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

Lets say, my file has following content and situated at /home/usr1/Documents/companyNames.txt

> Name1
>
> Name 2
>
> Name 3
>
> Millions of names...

I tried the following code:

```
$> var string = cat('home/usr1/Documents/companyNames.txt');
$> string = string.split('\n');
$> db.records.find({field: {$in: string}});
```

As per the code in link [Can I read a csv file inside of a Mongo Shell Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543159/can-i-read-a-csv-file-inside-of-a-mongo-shell-javascript-file)

This works if the file is small in size, but when the file has millions of lines it fails. The whole lines in the file is trying to fit inside the memory and gets crashed. Is there any other way to process big files inside Mongo shell with Java script?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo isn't very good with larges queries.

You might have to go the Javascript way :

```
var string = cat('home/usr1/Documents/companyNames.txt');
string = string.split('\n');
let results = [];
string.forEach(string => result.push(db.records.find({field: {$eq: string}})));
```

Comment: Memory crashes after the first line. I have more than 1 million lines in my file.

Comment: Externally split the file in multiple parts of reasonable size and iterate over them ? Anyway I would avoid using '$in' for even medium-sized arrays.

Comment: That would double my work, I loaded the file into another collection. Couldn't load large files inside mongo shell, I guess its not possible!